# How to ensure TFS build server gets updated Nuget packages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tfs, nuget, nuget-package-restore, azure-application-insights

I have an ASP.NET MVC website that was using the pre-release bits of Application Insights. I used the 'Manage Nuget Packages' option on the website to upgrade Application Insights to the latest version. Everything builds and runs successfully locally. All the App. Insights DLLs have been updated to v1.1.0. However when I try to run a gated build on TFS to check these changes in I keep getting the following error:

> This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this
>   computer(here it's pointing to the build server). Enable NuGet Package
>   Restore to download them.  For more information, see
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is
>   ....\packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Agent.Intercept.0.17.0\build\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Agent.Intercept.targets.

This only happens when the gated build runs on trying to check in. It results in the gated build failing which rejects my checking.

Is there anything that I can do here?

Comment: Have you enabled package restore on the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error i believe , you have not enabled automatic package restore option.

please enable this option to resolve the error , while nuget restore works.

Steps to enable :

Click on Tools -> Nuget Package Manager -> Package Manager Settings -->general --> check the option Automatically restore package while building .

This feature will download all packages which are referred by your packages.config files before building the code to make sure code has all references included while building the code.

Comment: This is enabled by default. The problem is not on my local dev. environment. The error is thrown by the build server. It is unable to get the nuget packages.

Comment: I think you need to actually enable package restore *on the build server*, via nuget command line or in VS if you also have VS installed on the build server.

Comment: Have you checked if nuget source are set correctly ? under package source field ?